# Maintain Xcode Run Script Phase after swift package generate-xcodeproj

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a Run Script phase in my Xcode project. After I update my dependencies with SPM via `swift package update` I have to update my project with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

Without using a rubygem, pod spec or other 3rd part tool, how Can I maintain that build phase? Can I add Run Script phase to xcconfig file somehow?

Answer (score 1):

With SwiftPM currently, the xcode project file is generated from a template, and any extensions on it are considered to be ephemeral - the recreation of the xcode project file only looks at what's in Package.swift, and not any existing projects. The result is that any extensions you add in (like a shell script build phase) are always going to be lost when you regenerate the script.

I recommend wrapping the whole project in a Makefile or something equivalent if you need to invoke a shell script or equiv kind of mechanism for your build, rather than extending the generated xcode project.